# How to disable MenuItem in play mode in Unity?

Tags: unity, menu

I created a function which snaps an object to pivot with a hotkey of **Shift + S**. When I play the game in which I run using **Shift** and move backwards using **S** I accidentally call the function. How can I have this MenuItem enabled only in Editor?

Here is the code in C#:

```
[MenuItem("GameObject/Snap/To pivot #s")] // snap to pivot
private static void SnapToPivot() {
    var selectedObjects = Selection.gameObjects;
    foreach (var obj in selectedObjects)
    {
        Undo.RecordObject(obj.transform, "Snap to pivot");
        obj.transform.position = SceneView.lastActiveSceneView.pivot;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding a guard clause to the top of your method?

```
if (Application.isPlaying)
    return;
```

This will halt execution of the shortcut command if the editor is in play mode.

A better solution might be to also check if the game window has focus, so you can still use the shortcut in the scene view while playing.

Comment: And for an even more consistent experience, you can disable the MenuItem too, while playing with the validator method : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html